# Creating a while loop for a non-simple piece of code

Tags: python, web-scraping, while-loop

I'm new to Python (and programming in general) and I'm having trouble creating a while loop. All the examples I've been able to find are pretty simple, along the lines of var=10, subtract 1 until you get to 0. I have a larger piece of code that I need to re-run as long as a condition is met, but what I've tried hasn't worked. I'm using Python 3 in Anaconda.

I've tried def main() and the below and now I'm trying while true (in my code sample, I have while true and below it is indented but I can't seem to get it to indent here). What I'm trying to get it to do is check whether datey is less than endDate and if it is, start the whole thing again.

Here's what I have:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
while True:

    WB = load_workbook('File.xlsx', data_only=True)
    SH = WB['02474']
    import datetime
    from datetime import timedelta
    endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-02-09', '%Y-%m-%d')

    MXrow = SH.max_row
    NXrow = MXrow+1
    datex = SH.cell(row=MXrow, column=2)
    datex2 = datex.value
    datey = datetime.datetime.strptime(datex2, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    datey2 = datey.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    URL = 'https://www.example.com' + str(datey2)

    import requests
    page = requests.get(URL)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

    mintemp = soup.find("tr",{"class":"weatherhistory_results_datavalue temp_mn"})
    for i in mintemp:
        mintemp2 = i.find("span",{"class": "value"})

    maxtemp = soup.find("tr",{"class":"weatherhistory_results_datavalue temp_mx"})
    for i in maxtemp:
        maxtemp2 = i.find("span",{"class": "value"})

    mintemp3 = mintemp2.text
    maxtemp3 = maxtemp2.text

    while(datey <= endDate):
        SH.cell(row=NXrow, column=1).value = "ZIP"
        SH.cell(row=NXrow, column=2).value = datey2
        SH.cell(row=NXrow, column=3).value = URL
        SH.cell(row=NXrow, column=4).value = mintemp3
        SH.cell(row=NXrow, column=5).value = maxtemp3
        WB.save('File.xlsx')
```

Would love any pointers you can give me to fix this!

Comment: I am sorry but the question is not very clear. What is the "larger piece of code" you need to re-run? The entire code?

Comment: If you want to "start the whole thing again", then you have to put "the whole thing" inside the `while` loop, not just the last few lines.

Comment: Ah yes, it's the whole code I want to re-run. I've tried putting the whole code in the while loop using def main() at the start, but it doesn't seem to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if

> datey is less than endDate

then simply use your while loop argument at the top instead of a boolean:

```
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

while(datey <= endDate):

    WB = load_workbook('File.xlsx', data_only=True)

    SH = WB['02474']
    endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-02-09', '%Y-%m-%d')

    MXrow = SH.max_row
    NXrow = MXrow+1
    datex = SH.cell(row=MXrow, column=2)
    datex2 = datex.value
    datey = datetime.datetime.strptime(datex2, '%Y-%m-%d') + 
    datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    datey2 = datey.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    URL = 'https://www.example.com' + str(datey2)


    page = requests.get(URL)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

    mintemp = soup.find("tr",{"class":"weatherhistory_results_datavalue temp_mn"})
    for i in mintemp:
        mintemp2 = i.find("span",{"class": "value"})

    maxtemp = soup.find("tr",{"class":"weatherhistory_results_datavalue temp_mx"})
    for i in maxtemp:
        maxtemp2 = i.find("span",{"class": "value"})

    mintemp3 = mintemp2.text
    maxtemp3 = maxtemp2.text

    SH.cell(row=NXrow, column=1).value = "ZIP"
    SH.cell(row=NXrow, column=2).value = datey2
    SH.cell(row=NXrow, column=3).value = URL
    SH.cell(row=NXrow, column=4).value = mintemp3
    SH.cell(row=NXrow, column=5).value = maxtemp3
    WB.save('File.xlsx')
```

This way, when 'datey' is less than or equal to 'endDate', the contents of the while loop will continue to loop until 'datey' is greater than 'endDate'

Also import statements go at the top of your file and do not belong inside a loop.

Comment: You need to update `datey` within the while loop somehow, otherwise you will get an infinite loop.

Comment: datey should change every time it goes through the loop. However, wouldn't I need to define datey and endDate before the while loop starts? Or does it look within the while loop for those definitions? This is where I keep getting confused.